# In django, does "migrate" just do database stuff?

Tags: django, migrate

I understand migrate sets up the database according to the migration, but the scope of it's operation seems to go beyond that.

When I ran manage.py migrate, not only did it apply the database migrations, which is good, but it also went through the main url.py and started to execute the methods I had in there which I would like only to be executed only once when the "web starts".

What does migrate actually do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`migrate` it is the django [command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/), so when you run it through `./manage.py` you also run django [setup()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#django.setup) and it validate(execute) project scripts.